# Ponteiro de ponteiro para alterar a minha pilha. Por que devo utilizá-los?

Tags: c, ponteiro, estrutura-de-dados, stack

Eu estou fazendo um código que consiste em analisar uma expressão aritmética, e verificar se quando abro um '(', então eu devo fechar um ')'. Ou seja, verificar se a expressão é válida ou não. Para isso implementei uma pilha para me auxiliar a resolver esse problema.

Todavia, percebi que devo utilizar um ponteiro de ponteiros nas minhas funções como `pop()`,`push()` e `verificasimbolo()`. Contudo, ainda não ficou claro para mim o por que desta implementação. Visto que em códigos que implementei uma lista encadeada simples, nas funções semelhantes eu apenas precisei de um ponteiro para fazer essas alterações.

Obrigado pela atenção.

Segue o meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ABRE_PARENTESE '('
#define FECHA_PARENTESE ')'

struct pilha {

    char elemento;
    struct pilha* prox;

};

typedef struct pilha PILHA;

int ehvazia(PILHA** p) {
    return *p == NULL;
}

void verifica(PILHA** p){
    if(*p == NULL) {
        printf("MEMORIA INDISPONIVEL\n");
        exit(1);
    }
} 

void push(PILHA** topo, char newElemento) {

    PILHA* newPtr = malloc(sizeof(PILHA));
    verifica(&newPtr);

    newPtr->elemento = newElemento;
    newPtr->prox = (*topo);
    (*topo) = newPtr;

    printf("%c foi inserido na pilha.\n", (*topo)->elemento);
    // free(newPtr);
}

void pop(PILHA** topo) {

    PILHA* tempPtr;
    tempPtr = malloc(sizeof(PILHA));
    verifica(&tempPtr);

    tempPtr = (*topo);
    (*topo) = (*topo)->prox;

    printf("%c foi removido da pilha.\n", tempPtr->elemento);
    free(tempPtr);

}

void verificaSimbolo(PILHA** topo, char simbolo) {

    if((simbolo == ABRE_PARENTESE)
        || (simbolo == FECHA_PARENTESE)) {

        if(ehvazia(topo)) {
            push(topo, simbolo);

        }
        else if(((*topo)->elemento == ABRE_PARENTESE)
            && (simbolo == FECHA_PARENTESE)){
            pop(topo);

        } else{
            push(topo, simbolo);
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    PILHA* topo = NULL;

    f       
        }
    }

    if(ehvazia(&topo))
        printf("Expressao valida\n");
    else 
        printf("Expressao invalida\n");

}
 for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; argv[i][j] != '\0'; j++) {
            verificaSimbolo(&topo, argv[i][j]);

        }
    }

    if(ehvazia(&topo))
        printf("Expressao valida\n");
    else 
        printf("Expressao invalida\n");

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consideremos o seguinte exemplo, fazer uma função que altere o valor de um inteiro. Poderíamos começar com uma abordagem simplista (embora errada):

```
void alteraInt(int numero){
    numero = 10;
}
```

E chama-la no main:

```
int x = 2;
alteraInt(x);
printf("%d",x);
```

Que mostra:

> 2

E agora podemos ficar a pensar, mas porque ? se ele foi alterado na função ?

**Em c por defeito os valores são passados para as funções por cópia**, logo o parâmetro `numero` na função `alteraInt()` é uma copia do `x`! Por isso alterar o `numero` não função não altera o `x` do main.

Como podemos então fazer para alterar mesmo o `x` ?

Em vez de passarmos o `numero` passamos o endereço onde ele está em memoria, que dessa forma conseguimos ir ao local onde ele está e altera-lo. Comecemos então por alterar a função `alteraInt()` para receber o ponteiro em vez de um inteiro:

```
void alteraInt(int *numero){ //agora recebe ponteiro
    *numero = 10; //agora diz que o valor que está no endereço recebido passa a ser 10
}
```

A chamada também se ia alterar:

```
alteraInt(&x); //agora com o & para passar o endereço do x e não o valor
```

Que já mostra o esperado:

> 10

Vamos agora transpor este principio para um ponteiro. Se tivermos um ponteiro e quisermos alterar o ponteiro numa função voltamos ao mesmo problema.

```
void alteraPonteiro(int *ponteiro){
    ponteiro = 20; //só para exemplificar vamos colocar o endereço 20 no ponteiro
}
```

E agora chamar essa função com um ponteiro:

```
int x = 2;
int *p = &x; //ponteiro p aponta para o x
printf ("Antes %p", p);
alteraPonteiro(p);
printf ("\nDepois %p", p);
```

Que apresenta:

> Antes 0028FF18
>
> Depois 0028FF18

O ponteiro não foi alterado porque copiamos o valor do ponteiro para dentro da função. Quando se altera dentro da função está-se a alterar uma copia do ponteiro e não o ponteiro original.

Como podemos corrigir isso?

Aplicando o mesmo principio, e agora passar um ponteiro para este ponteiro, para que a função saiba onde ir à memoria para alterar. Então a função fica agora:

```
void alteraPonteiro(int **ponteiro){ //agora ponteiro de ponteiro
    *ponteiro = 20; //agora com * para ser o valor apontado
}
```

E na chamada também se altera:

```
alteraPonteiro(&p); //agora passa o endereço do ponteiro em vez do valor dele
```

Resultado:

> Antes 0028FF18
>
> Depois 00000014

Aqui vemos que conseguimos alterar o valor do ponteiro, e por ele a apontar para o endereço 20.

Mas está 14 no resultado !?

Isto é porque quando escrevemos o valor de um ponteiro com `%p` ele por defeito é apresentado em hexadecimal, e 0x14 em hexadecimal corresponde a 20 em decimal.

**E porque tem de ser dessa forma na fila ?**

No main temos um ponteiro que representa a fila:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    PILHA* topo = NULL;
```

E em algumas funções queremos alterar o valor desse ponteiro, para por a apontar para outro nó, como por exemplo no push:

```
void push(PILHA** topo, char newElemento) {
    ...
    (*topo) = newPtr;
```

Se receber um ponteiro normal de pilha, um `PILHA*` , esse será uma cópia do que existe no main e por isso não altera o que temos no main. Em vez disso tem de ser como está nó código e receber o endereço de memória onde está o ponteiro do main, para que a função possa ir a esse local e alterar.

**Conclusão**

Se temos uma variável de um determinado tipo e a queremos alterar dentro de uma função, temos que receber um ponteiro para ela na função, caso contrário estamos a alterar uma copia dessa variável.

Comment: Eu entendi agora. Muito obrigado Isac =)