# Alterar endereço de ponteiro em uma funçào

Tags: c

Estou tendo problemas para alterar o endereço de um ponteiro dentro de uma função. Eu declaro o ponteiro dentro da função, então passo ele por parâmetro para outra função. Esta outra função deve fazer com que o ponteiro passe a apontar para outro endereço. O problema é que assim que essa função termina e retorna para a função que a chamou, o ponteiro não sofre nenhuma alteração.

```
//imports
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define tam_max_bucket 2

int dir_prof=0;

typedef struct Buck{
 int profundidade;
 int contador;
 int chaves[tam_max_bucket];
}bucket;

typedef struct dir{
 struct Buck *bucket_ref;
}dir_cell;

dir_cell *diretorio;

int make_address(int key, int profundidade){
 int retVal, mask, hashVal, lowBit;
 retVal = 0;
 mask = 1;
 hashVal = key;
 int j;
 for(j=0; j<profundidade; j++){
    retVal = retVal << 1;
    lowBit = hashVal & mask;
    retVal = retVal | lowBit;
    hashVal = hashVal >> 1;
 }
return retVal;
}

int op_find(int key, bucket *found_bucket){
  int address = make_address(key, dir_prof);
  found_bucket = diretorio[address].bucket_ref;
  printf("\n%d\n", found_bucket->profundidade);
  printf("\n%d\n", diretorio[address].bucket_ref->contador);
  printf("\n%d\n", found_bucket->contador);
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<found_bucket->contador; i++){
      if(key == found_bucket->chaves[i])
        return 1;
  }
  return -1;
}

int op_add(int key){
  bucket *found_bucket = (bucket *) malloc(sizeof(bucket));
  printf("\nCont - %d\n", found_bucket->contador); //Imprime o valor do contador assim que found_bucket é alocada
  if(op_find(key, found_bucket) == 1){
    return -1;
  }
  printf("\nNovo valor%d\n", found_bucket->contador); //Imprime o valor de contador de found_bucket após a chamada da função. O valor não se altera, continua o mesmo
  return 1;
  }

void main(){
  diretorio =(dir_cell *) malloc(1*sizeof(dir_cell));
  diretorio[0].bucket_ref =(bucket *) malloc(sizeof(bucket));
  diretorio[0].bucket_ref->profundidade = 0;
  diretorio[0].bucket_ref->contador = 0;
  FILE *chaves;
  chaves = fopen("chaves.txt", "r+");
  if(chaves!=NULL){
      int chave;
      while((fscanf(chaves, "%d\n", &chave))!=EOF){
           printf("%d", chave);
           op_add(chave);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Este código está confuso e feito de uma forma longe do ideal, então mesmo que arrume este problema, ele ainda estará longe de ser um código adequado. Este talvez seja só o sintoma e só uma reformulação resolveria tudo mesmo. O código term um estilo bem inconsistente. Onde ocorre o problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> O problema é que assim que essa função termina e retorna para a que a
>   chamou, o ponteiro não sofre nenhuma alteração

É verdade pois o valor do ponteiro foi copiado para a outra função, na função `op_add` que chama a `op_find`:

```
int op_add(int key){
  bucket *found_bucket = (bucket *) malloc(sizeof(bucket));
  ...
  if(op_find(key, found_bucket) == 1){
```

Na expectativa que a função `op_find` mudasse o seu valor:

```
int op_find(int key, bucket *found_bucket){
  ...
  found_bucket = diretorio[address].bucket_ref;
```

Mas esta recebeu uma copia do ponteiro, logo não altera o original.

A solução para este problema passa por passar o endereço do ponteiro, ou seja um ponteiro para um ponteiro, assim:

```
int op_find(int key, bucket **found_bucket){ //alterada
  int address = make_address(key, dir_prof);
  *found_bucket = diretorio[address].bucket_ref; //atribuição com base no ponteiro para ponteiro
  printf("\n%d\n", (*found_bucket)->profundidade); //alterada
  printf("\n%d\n", diretorio[address].bucket_ref->contador);
  printf("\n%d\n", (*found_bucket)->contador); //alterada
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<(*found_bucket)->contador; i++){ //alterada
      if(key == (*found_bucket)->chaves[i]) //alterada
        return 1;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Para além disso sempre dentro desta ultima função `op_add` mudamos o ponteiro, com:

```
*found_bucket = diretorio[address].bucket_ref; //modifica o ponteiro
```

Aqui temos uma fuga de memória pois tinha sido alocado um *bucket* na função anterior, em:

```
bucket *found_bucket = (bucket *) malloc(sizeof(bucket));
```

Que não foi libertado, sendo assim necessário fazer `free` do ponteiro anterior antes de mudar, ou criar so o ponteiro sem alocar memoria.

Por fim não nos podemos esquecer que o C não inicializa a memória, logo aceder a uma estrutura que foi alocada sem atribuir valores iniciais vai dar valores aleatórios, como é visível aqui:

```
bucket *found_bucket = (bucket *) malloc(sizeof(bucket));
printf("\nCont - %d\n", found_bucket->contador); //não é possível garantir o valor aqui, pois não foi inicializado
```

Caso não seja muito claro o motivo da alteração dos ponteiros:

[Leitura adicional sobre o porque de ser ponteiro para ponteiro, em vez de ponteiro normal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220053/ponteiro-de-ponteiro-para-alterar-a-minha-pilha-por-que-devo-utiliz%C3%A1-los/220063#220063)