# Implementação de Árvore Binária - Linguagem C

Tags: c

Estou tentando fazer uma inserção de nodos em árvore.

Eu estou usando este código, mas há uma série de pequenos erros que eu não consigo compreender o porquê dos erros.

O último deles é relacionado ao **valor1**, que não está declarada. Entretanto eu preciso que meu nodo **novo** receba um valor para fazer comparações de menor e maior da **struct registro** para ir sendo adicionado na ávore.

```
void insere_Arvore(nodo* raiz, struct registro_st registro){
    if(raiz == NULL)
        {
        return 0;
        }
    nodo* novo = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    if(novo == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    novo->dado->valor = valor1;
    novo->dir = NULL;
    novo->esq= NULL;
        if(*raiz = NULL)
        {
            *raiz = novo;
        }
    else{
    nodo* atual = *raiz;
    nodo* ant = NULL;
    }

        while(atual != NULL)
            {
            ant = atual;
            if (valor1 == atual->dado->valor){
                            free(novo);
                            return 0;
            }

        if(valor1 > atual->dado->valor)
                                    {
                    atual = atual->dir
    }
        else{
                    atual = atual->esq;
        }
        if(valor1 > ant->dado->valor)
                                    {
        ant->dir = novo;
        }
        else{
        ant->esq = novo;
        }
        if(valor > ant->dado->valor){
            ant->dir = novo;
        }
        else{
        ant->esq = novo;
        }
        }
            }
        return 1;
}
```

Código completo:

```
typedef struct registro_st{         // sequência de objetos do mesmo tipo
    char login[50];
    char nome[50];
    float valor;
    struct registro *prox;
} registro;

typedef struct nodo_st{
    registro *dado;
    struct nodo_st *dir;
    struct nodo_st *esq;
} nodo;

typedef struct Lista_st{
    nodo *cabeca;
    nodo *cauda;
    int tamanho;
} lista;

void insere_Arvore(nodo* raiz, struct registro_st registro){
    if(raiz == NULL)
        {
        return 0;
        }
    nodo* novo = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    if(novo == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    novo->dado->valor = valor1;
    novo->dir = NULL;
    novo->esq= NULL;
        if(*raiz = NULL)
        {
            *raiz = novo;
        }
    else{
    nodo* atual = *raiz;
    nodo* ant = NULL;
    }

        while(atual != NULL)
            {
            ant = atual;
            if (valor1 == atual->dado->valor){
                            free(novo);
                            return 0;
            }

        if(valor1 > atual->dado->valor)
                                    {
                    atual = atual->dir
    }
        else{
                    atual = atual->esq;
        }
        if(valor1 > ant->dado->valor)
                                    {
        ant->dir = novo;
        }
        else{
        ant->esq = novo;
        }
        if(valor > ant->dado->valor){
            ant->dir = novo;
        }
        else{
        ant->esq = novo;
        }
        }
            }
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: `return 0;`  Alteração: 'deve ser' return;

Comment: `Para facilidade de legibilidade e compreensão, ignore constantemente o código. Descarte após cada abraçadeira aberta, sem energia antes de cada armadura de fechamento.  Sugere que cada nível de travessura seja de 4 espaços

Comment: Em C, as funções de alocação de heap (malloc, calloc, realloc) retornam` void * `que podem ser atribuídas a qualquer ponteiro, o Casting apenas obstrua o código.

Comment: `nodo* novo =`    É muito pobre prática de programação muito fraca para nomear variáveis O mesmo que um nome de tipo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem várias coisas que não estão muito corretas.

- Para poder modificar o raiz dentro da função tem de ser passado um ponteiro para o ponteiro, em vez de um ponteiro normal ([mais nesse tópico se quiser ler](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220053/ponteiro-de-ponteiro-para-alterar-a-minha-pilha-por-que-devo-utiliz%C3%A1-los/220063#220063)).
- É incorreto utilizar retornos com valores tipo `0` ou `1` numa função `void`.
- O laço/ciclo deve ser apenas utilizado para chegar ao nó correto a a inserção feita somente após isso.

Logo o código deverá ficar da seguinte forma:

```
//A raiz passou a **raiz, e registro a *registro
void insere_Arvore(nodo **raiz, struct registro_st *registro) {
    nodo* novo = malloc(sizeof(nodo)); //agora sem cast pois é desnecessário
    if(novo == NULL){
        return; // é void logo não pode ter tipo de retorno
    }

    novo->dado = registro; //o dado é o registro todo em si
    novo->dir = NULL;
    novo->esq= NULL;

    if(*raiz == NULL){ //ver se o valor do ponteiro é null, logo arvore vazia
        *raiz = novo;
        return;
    }

    nodo* atual = *raiz;
    nodo* ant = NULL;

    while(atual != NULL){ // laço/ciclo agora só para navegar até ao sitio correto
        ant = atual;

        //o valor a ser inserido vem no próprio registro, com registro->valor
        if (registro->valor == atual->dado->valor){
            free(novo);
            return; // é void logo não pode ter tipo de retorno
        }

        if(registro->valor > atual->dado->valor){
            atual = atual->dir;
        }
        else{
            atual = atual->esq;
        }
    }

    //após navegar é feita a inserção pelo no anterior.
    if (registro->valor > ant->dado->valor){ //se maior que o anterior fica a direita
        ant->dir = novo;
    }
    else { //senão fica a esquerda
        ant->esq = novo;
    }
}
```

O main naturalmente também ficará um pouco diferente:

```
int main(){
    nodo *arvore = NULL;

    registro *reg = malloc(sizeof(registro));
    strcpy(reg->nome, "O nome aqui");
    strcpy(reg->login, "O login aqui");
    reg->valor = 10;


    insere_Arvore(&arvore, reg); 
    //            ^-- agora com o endereço de arvore

    //...
```