# Lista encadeada retornando vazia fora da função

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, struct, lista-encadeada

Estou tentando ler os dados de um arquivo `.obj` e inserir em uma lista encadeada, tenho uma função pra ler e dentro dela chamo a função de inserir. Quando eu chamo a função de imprimir a lista dentro da função de ler após ter inserido todos os valores funciona normalmente, mas quando chamo na mais após a chamada da função que lê os dados ela está ficando vazia.

Definição da `struct`.

```
typedef struct listaVertice{
   int id;
   float x,y,z;
   struct listaVertice *prox;
}ListaVertice;
```

Função que lê os dados do arquivo e chama a função de inserir na lista

```
void LerArquivo(ListaVertice *lv, ListaFace *lf){
FILE *fp;
float x,y,z;
int f1,f2,f3,f4;
int idVertice = 1;
char operacao;

fp = fopen("cubo.obj","r");
if(!fp)
{
    printf("\nErro ao abrir o arquivo!");
    exit(1);
}

while(fscanf(fp,"%c",&operacao)!= EOF){

    if(operacao == 'v'){
        fscanf(fp,"%f" "%f" "%f",&x,&y,&z);
        //chamada da função de inserir na lista
        lv = InserirVertice(lv,x,y,z,idVertice);
        idVertice++;
    }else if(operacao == 'f'){
        fscanf(fp,"%d" "%d" "%d %d",&f1,&f2,&f3,&f4);
        lf = InserirFace(lf,f1,f2,f3,f4);
    }
}
 //Seu realizar a chamada da função que imprime neste ponto a lista é impressa corretamente
}
```

Função que imprime a lista

```
void ImprimirListaVertice(ListaVertice *lv){
ListaVertice *aux;
   while(aux !=NULL){
    printf("v(%d): %f %f %f\n",aux->id,aux->x,aux->y,aux->z);
    aux = aux->prox;
   }
}
```

Se eu realizar a chamada na main, não imprime nada, como se a lista estivesse vazia.Por exemplo:

```
main(){
  LerArquivo(lv,lf);
  ImprimirListaVertice(lv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema está nestas duas instruções, dentro da função `LerArquivo`:

```
void LerArquivo(ListaVertice *lv, ListaFace *lf){
    ...
    lv = InserirVertice(lv,x,y,z,idVertice);
    ...
    lf = InserirFace(lf,f1,f2,f3,f4);
```

Os parâmetros `lv` e `lf` são na verdade copias daqueles estão no `main`, e por isso altera-los dentro desta função não altera os que estão no `main`.

A solução é passar como parâmetro o endereço dos ponteiros para que a função possa ir lá e alterar os seus valores.

Então a sua função passaria a ficar assim:

```
void LerArquivo(ListaVertice **lv, ListaFace **lf){ //agora duplo ponteiro nos 2
    ...
    *lv = InserirVertice(lv,x,y,z,idVertice); //agora com *
    ...
    *lf = InserirFace(lf,f1,f2,f3,f4); //agora com *
```

E o `main` também se tinha que alterar para:

```
main(){
  LerArquivo(&lv,&lf); //agora com & para passar o endereço
  ImprimirListaVertice(lv);
}
```

Repare que apenas foi mudada a função `LerArquivo` pois é a unica que tenta alterar os ponteiros que tinha no `main`. A `ImprimirListaVertice` apenas utiliza o ponteiro.

[Leitura relacionada que recomendo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220053/ponteiro-de-ponteiro-para-alterar-a-minha-pilha-por-que-devo-utiliz%C3%A1-los/220063#220063)