# Pilhas com alocação sequencial

Tags: array, c++, struct, stack

Estou tendo problemas para implementar o código de uma pilha utilizando vetores:

```
typedef struct pilha pilha;
struct pilha
{

    int *v;
    int topo;
    int tam_max;
};



void Inicializar_Pilha (pilha pi, int tam_max)
{

    pi.v=new int [tam_max];
    pi.topo=-1;
    pi.tam_max=tam_max;
    return;
}
```

Aparentemente `pi.topo` e `pi.tam_max` não está sendo armazenado, mas o programa executa e depois para de responder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função `Inicializar_Pilha` deve receber um ponteiro para `pilha` e não `pilha`, para que consiga alterar o objeto que tem no `main`.
Logo a essa função deveria ser estar assim:

```
void Inicializar_Pilha (pilha *pi, int tam_max) //agora com * para ser ponteiro
{

    pi->v=new int [tam_max]; //-> em vez de . porque é ponteiro
    pi->topo=-1; //agora com ->
    pi->tam_max=tam_max;//agora com ->
    //return; //return no fim de uma função void não faz sentido
}
```

E o `main` algo como:

```
int main(){
    pilha p1;
    Inicializar_Pilha(&p1, 10); //aqui passado com & para ser o endereço do objeto

    cout<<p1.topo<<" "<<p1.tam_max; //-1 10

    return 0;
}
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/uTLTba)

O problema é que como tem no seu código a função `InicializarPilha` recebe uma copia do objeto original que tem no `main`, e por isso as alterações feitas na função são feitas numa copia e não afetam a `pilha` que está no `main`.

[Leitura relacionado que recomendo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220053/ponteiro-de-ponteiro-para-alterar-a-minha-pilha-por-que-devo-utiliz%C3%A1-los/220063#220063)