# Como posso abrir um arquivo em uma função void?

Tags: c, arquivo, ponteiro

Estou tentando abrir um arquivo de texto em uma função `int abreArquivoEntrada`, e para isso estou mandando como parâmetro o ponteiro do tipo `FILE` e o um vetor de `char` contendo o nome do arquivo, dentro da função utilizo a função de `fopen`, porem quando printo o ponteiro de arquivo depois da execução da função, ele não mudou.

Grato desde já.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct PESSOA{
    char nome[50];
    int idade;
    float altura;
};

void leNomeArquivoEntrada(char* S1){
    printf("Nome do arquivo: ");
    scanf("%s",S1);
}

int abreArquivoEntrada(FILE *Arq , char* S1){

    Arq = fopen(S1,"r");

    printf("Na funcao %d \n", Arq);

    if(Arq == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;

}

void fechaArquivo(FILE *Arq){

    fclose(Arq);
}

int main()
{
   char S1[50], inf[50];

    struct PESSOA Povo[10], P;
    FILE *Arq;
    int i;

    leNomeArquivoEntrada(S1);

    printf("Na main antes da bertura %d \n", Arq);


    if(abreArquivoEntrada(Arq, S1) == 1){


        printf("Na main %d \n", Arq);
        fscanf(Arq,"%s", &P.nome);
        fscanf(Arq,"%d", &P.idade);
        fscanf(Arq,"%f", &P.altura);
        printf("%s \n", P.nome);
        printf("%d \n", P.idade);
        printf("%f \n", P.altura);



        fechaArquivo(Arq);

    }
    else printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não consegui compreender o que você quer fazer. Você gostaria de exibir o conteúdo do arquivo na função `leNomeArquivoEntrada()`, seria isto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em C os parâmetros são passados por cópia. Se pretende alterar o valor na função pode passar o endereço do valor que quer alterar, ao invés do valor em si. No seu caso teria de mandar para a função o endereço do `FILE*` que tem, utilizando `&`:

```
if(abreArquivoEntrada(&Arq, S1) == 1){
//--------------------^
```

A função passa a ter que receber um ponteiro de `FILE*` ou seja um `FILE**`.

Fazendo os respetivos ajustes na função ficaria assim:

```
int abreArquivoEntrada(FILE **Arq , char* S1){
//--------------------------^ duplo ponteiro agora

    *Arq = (fopen(S1,"r")); //*Arq em vez de Arq

    if(*Arq == NULL) //*Arq em vez de Arq
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

A troca baseou-se quase em alterar `Arq` para `*Arq`.

Uma alternativa comum é devolver o novo valor que quer para o ponteiro, no entanto como já estava a utilizar um retorno de `int` essa solução ficou inviabilizada.

Recomendo que leia também essa minha resposta no assunto que irá ajudar-lhe a perceber melhor o porquê:
 [Ponteiro de ponteiro para alterar a minha pilha. Por que devo utilizá-los?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220053/ponteiro-de-ponteiro-para-alterar-a-minha-pilha-por-que-devo-utiliz%C3%A1-los/220063#220063)

Comment: Obrigado Isac, sua explicação ajudou mto.

Comment: @jaojpaulo Fico contente que tenha ficado claro. Estamos cá para ajudar.